# How to autofill multiple cells with a formula using dynamic range

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I have one dynamic table that is created based on the multiplication of Cells(4,"D") and Cells(6,"D") that gives the total number of rows. The column number is fixed and defined from B to G. The first row with data is line 13.

I want to write a formula deltaMassFormula that introduces in column B the following: deltaMassFormula = D13 * (G13 - F13) and automatically it fills down until the countRows equals the total number of rows (multiplication variable)

For instance, if multiplication = 4 then

E13 = D13 * (G13 - F13)

E14 = D14 * (G14 - F14)

E15 = D15 * (G15 - F15)

E16 = D16 * (G16 - F16)

**My Code**:

```
 Dim StartCellM As Range    
 Dim lastRow As Long    
 Dim deltaMassFormula As Integer    
 Dim multiplication As Integer

 multiplication = Cells(4, "D").Value * Cells(6, "D").Value    
 countRows = multiplication - 1

 Set StartCellM = Cells(13, "E")    
 Set lastRow = Cells(13, "E") + countRows

 deltaMassFormula = Cells(13, "D") * (Cells(13, "G") - Cells(13, "F"))

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)     
    .Range("E13").Formula = deltaMassFormula    
    .Range("E13:E" & lastRow).FillDown    
 End With
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What problems do you encounter with the code you've posted?

Comment: The problem is the code does not fill the cells below E13.

Answer (score 0):

This will fill the actual formula into the range and then replace it with the values. I also changed `lastrow` to long so it can be used in the other lines correctly and pulled the starting row from your range.

```
 Dim StartCellM As Range
 Dim lastRow As Long
 Dim multiplication As Integer

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 
     multiplication = .Range("D4").Value * .Range("D6").Value
     countRows = multiplication - 1

     Set StartCellM = .Range("E13")
     lastRow = StartCellM.Row + countRows

    .Range("E13:E" & lastRow).Formula = "=D13*(G13-F13)"
    .Range("E13:E" & lastRow).Value = .Range("E13:E" & lastRow).Value 'Remove this line to keep formula
 End With
```

The formula will break if you change the row your start cell is on and don't change the row in the formula to match so this code will use the row from `StartCellM` in the formula instead of hard coding it.

```
Dim StartCellM As Range
Dim lastRow As Long, startRow As Long
Dim multiplication As Integer

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    multiplication = .Range("D4").Value * .Range("D6").Value
    countRows = multiplication - 1

    Set StartCellM = .Range("E13")

    startRow = StartCellM.Row
    lastRow = startRow + countRows

    .Range("E" & startRow & ":E" & lastRow).Formula = "=D" & startRow & "*(G" & startRow & "-F" & startRow & ")"
    .Range("E" & startRow & ":E" & lastRow).Value = .Range("E" & startRow & ":E" & lastRow).Value 'Remove this line to keep formula
End With
```

I also moved everything inside the `With` so it will pull all the values from the correct sheet.

Comment: Thanks tjb1. It works perfectly. I will now compare both codes to see what was missing.

Comment: if you use this solution, I recommend to check (and maybe use) "value2" instead of "value". (For differences between them, just google it...)

Comment: Is there any difference in the computation time by using Value2 instead of Value? I went search the difference and it is mainly in Value2 it does not include Date or Currency. Since I am defining the variable type, how does it affect in this solution?

Comment: If it was formatted as a date in the worksheet it would return a different value using `value` vs `value2`.

Comment: as far as I know it doesn't depend on your variable type, but on your cell format.
e.g.: format cell E5 to currency, then run this macro:
`Sub test()
Dim i As Double
    Cells(4, 5).Value = 12.12345
    Cells(5, 5).Value = 12.12345
    i = Cells(5, 5).Value
    Cells(7, 5).Value = i
    i = Cells(5, 5).Value2
    Cells(8, 5).Value = i
End Sub`
it enters the value 12.12345 into cell E4 and E5. Then it takes the value of cell E5 into a Double variant and then enters **value** into E7 and **value2** into E8. You lost precision using **value**, while you kept it using **value2**.

Answer (score 0):

it fills the column B with the formula:

```
Sub filler()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim multiplication As Integer

    multiplication = Cells(4, 4).Value * Cells(6, 4).Value

    startRow = 13
    lastRow = startRow + multiplication - 1

    For i = startRow To lastRow
        Cells(i, 2).Formula = "=D" & i & "*(G" & i & "-F" & i & ")"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: tretom, you first define the formula for the starting cell and then you are moving downward the position of cells right? I am really green in programming. I am starting with vba.

Comment: oh sorry, I just forgot to erase your deltaMassFormula. I didn't use it. You just have to tell the first row and last row, then loop through the rows, and set the formula property of the given cell - in this case cell(i, 2), what could be written as you used it: cell(i, "B") - to to the string, built on the right side of the equation

Comment: Understood. Thank you tretom.